# NoSuchElementException when loading code using Selenium on Heroku

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, heroku, nosuchelementexception

Error:

```
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved

2022-03-14T14:08:52.425684+00:00 app[worker.1]: future: <Task finished name='Task-30' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py:407> exception=NoSuchElementException('no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".media-cards-grid"}\n  (Session info: headless chrome=99.0.4844.51)', None, ['#0 0x5586a25c17d3 <unknown>', '#1 0x5586a231d688 <unknown>', '#2 0x5586a2353c21 <unknown>', '#3 0x5586a2353de1 <unknown>', '#4 0x5586a2386d74 <unknown>', '#5 0x5586a23716dd <unknown>', '#6 0x5586a2384a0c <unknown>', '#7 0x5586a23715a3 <unknown>', '#8 0x5586a2346ddc <unknown>', '#9 0x5586a2347de5 <unknown>', '#10 0x5586a25f249d <unknown>', '#11 0x5586a260b60c <unknown>', '#12 0x5586a25f4205 <unknown>', '#13 0x5586a260bee5 <unknown>', '#14 0x5586a25e8070 <unknown>', '#15 0x5586a2627488 <unknown>', '#16 0x5586a262760c <unknown>', '#17 0x5586a2640c6d <unknown>', '#18 0x7f9745a5d609 <unknown>', ''])>
```

Here is the problematic part of the code:

```
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(link)
    block = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='media-cards-grid')
    all_image = block.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='media-card')
    all_image = all_image[0:10]

    for image in all_image:
        image_link = image.get_attribute('data-src')
        name = image.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'media-card__title').text
        ref = image.get_attribute('href')
        manga = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        manga.add(InlineKeyboardButton(name, url=ref))
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, photo=image_link, reply_markup=manga)
    shwmrrslts = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    shwmrrslts.add(InlineKeyboardButton('show more results', url=link))
    await callback.message.answer('if you want to see more, click on the button', reply_markup=shwmrrslts)
```

I searched for a solution on the internet but never found it.
also, this code worked fine from my computer:

```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(link)
    block = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'media-cards-grid')
    all_image = block.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'media-card')
    all_image = all_image[0:10]
    # print(type(all_image))
    for image in all_image:
        image_link = image.get_attribute('data-src')
        name = image.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'media-card__title').text
        ref = image.get_attribute('href')
        manga = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        manga.add(InlineKeyboardButton(name, url=ref))
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, photo=image_link, reply_markup=manga)
    shwmrrslts = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    shwmrrslts.add(InlineKeyboardButton('show more results', url=link))
    await callback.message.answer('if you want to see more, click on the button', reply_markup=shwmrrslts)
```

sorry for my bad english, thanks in advance
sorry

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
NoSuchElementException('no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".media-cards-grid"
```

...implies that the *NoSuchElementException* was raised when trying to locate the desired element through the following [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

```
(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='media-cards-grid')
```

You need to construct a more canonical [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447) which identifies the element uniquely within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes)

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [***NoSuchElementException***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995294/7429447) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315715/7429447)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442511/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

Hello Dan I have been struggling with this today and the problem is that Heroku is slower than your computer to manage Chrome, so you must let Heroku finish their job. To do this was useful to me import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

With this methods you can transform a `find_element` function such as

```
block = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='media-cards-grid')
```

In to

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
block = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'media-cards-grid')))
```

Notice that `EC.presence_of_all_elements_located` is also developed, just in case you needed. If the problem persists, increase the time of wait, i.e. the 20.

Hope this will solve your problem!